# deezer android sdk, add tracks to playlists

Tags: deezer

Is it possible to add tracks to playlists with the Deezer Android SDK?

When creating the DeezerRequest, there doesn't seem to be any way to set the method to 'POST' instead of 'GET'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DeezerRequest object has three constructor methods, illustrated below :

```
// Creates a GET request with the given path
DeezerRequest request = new DeezerRequest("artist/27");

// Creates a GET request with the given path and query parameters
Bundle params = new Bundle(1);
params.putString("q", "Daft Punk"); 
DeezerRequest request = new DeezerRequest("search/artist", params);

// Creates a POST request with the given path and parameters
Bundle params = new Bundle(1); 
params.putString("songs", "1234567,4567891,7891234");
DeezerRequest request = new DeezerRequest("search/artist", params, "POST");
```